# Nested tabulation in Java

Tags: java, string, oop

In class Groups that can hold Figures and other Groups i have a method toString

```
public String toString() {
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("Group consists of:\n");
        for (BaseFigure figure : this.group) {
            str.append("\t").append(figure.toString()).append("\n");
        }
        return str.toString();
    }
```

Calling this method i want to see an understable text display of nested Groups like that

```
Group consists of:
    Group consists of:
        Rectangle with center at (20.0, 10.0), and width: 15.0, height: 15.0, angle: 45.0
        Rectangle with center at (0.0, 0.0), and width: 7.0, height: 19.0, angle: 90.0
    Group consists of:
        Circle with center at (100.0, 100.0) and radius: 1.0
        Circle with center at (5.0, 0.0) and radius: 9.0

    Rectangle with center at (10.0, 10.0), and width: 10.0, height: 40.0, angle: 0.0
    Circle with center at (0.0, 0.0) and radius: 55.0
```

But 4th line somehow ignores multiple \t signs and puts at every line just one \t and displays like that:

```
Group consists of:
    Group consists of:
    Rectangle with center at (10.0, 10.0), and width: 10.0, height: 15.0, angle: 0.0
    Rectangle with center at (20.0, 10.0), and width: 15.0, height: 15.0, angle: 45.0
    Rectangle with center at (0.0, 0.0), and width: 7.0, height: 19.0, angle: 90.0
    Group consists of:
    Circle with center at (0.0, 0.0) and radius: 10.0
    Circle with center at (100.0, 100.0) and radius: 1.0
    Circle with center at (5.0, 0.0) and radius: 9.0
```

I tried replacing every \t with double \t, but it didn't work

```
public String toString() {
        String str = "Group consists of:\n";
        for (BaseFigure figure : this.group) {
            if (figure instanceof Group) {
                String newStr = figure.toString();
                str += newStr.replace("\t", "\t\t");
            } else {
                str += figure.toString();
            }
        }
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't really ignore anything. You only output one tab at the start of the whole string. But then the string itself consists of several line, and each line of course starts from the left again. It doesn't have a way to know it should copy the tab from the previous line. You need programming logic to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple of sub-groups each holding some figures, and a couple of figures.

Each sub-group will return something like this for it's toString():

```
Group X
    Figure Y
    Figure Z
```

Or one can say it is `Group X\n\tFigure Y\n\tFigure Z\n`.

Your code does this `StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder("Group consists of:\n");` and `str.append("\t").append(figure.toString()).append("\n")`, where `figure.toString()` returns the String above.

So you end up with: `Group consists of:\n\t<whatever toString() for subgroup returned>\n`.

Given that toString() has value of `Group X\n\tFigure Y\n\tFigure Z\n`, as mentioned, above, we end up with this: `Group consists of:\n\tGroup X\n\tFigure Y\n\tFigure Z\n\n`. As you can see, there is always only one tab before figures in the subgroup as a result. Because there are linebreaks inside of the String produced by toString(), and we don't have control over what's in the beginning of the line in there.

So in the end it looks like this:

```
Group consists of:
    Group X
    Figure Y
    Figure Z
```

So how do we make it into this?

```
Group consists of:
    Group X
        Figure Y
        Figure Z
```

One hacky way would be to replace each line break inside of the String returned by toString() with a line break followed by a tab. This would work with nesting, since parent group would do the same, and thus add another tab.

You tried something similar, but you wanted to replace a tab with two tabs. It's kinda wrong because there isn't necessarily going to be a tab at the beginning of each line in whatever toString() produces, and you forgot to add a tab of your own.

Try this instead:

```
public String toString() {
        String str = "Group consists of:\n";
        for (BaseFigure figure : this.group) {
            if (figure instanceof Group) {
                String newStr = figure.toString();
                str += "\t" + newStr.replace("\n", "\n\t") + "\n";
            } else {
                str += "\t" + figure.toString() + "\n";
            }
        }
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It returns the next https://ibb.co/sQ9mcf6

Comment: Oh, wait - there's a line break missing in the end. Let me correct the answer.

Comment: Try the updated version please

Comment: The result is the same as in question, it doesn't work

Comment: You should add "\t" in the else block, then it works. Edit your answer and i will mark it as a solution

Comment: Ah, right. Thanks. Done!